# java.awt drawRect() wrongly interprets "width" and "height" (produces +1 pixel right and down)

Tags: swing, awt, drawrect

I have started exercising with Swing programming and found one really weird thing which I consider as a bug in the basics.

The below example shows that "width" and "height" values are treated differently when we create a Rectangle and when we display it.

```
import java.awt.*;
//  I create a rectangle 2 x 2 with height=2, width=2
Rectangle rec = new Rectangle(1, 1, 2, 2);

// I make sure that it contains only 4 points: (1,1), (1,2), (2,1), (2,2)
println("- " + rec.contains(1, 1) + ", " + rec.contains(1, 2) + ", " + rec.contains(1, 3));
println("- " + rec.contains(2, 1) + ", " + rec.contains(2, 2) + ", " + rec.contains(2, 3));
println("- " + rec.contains(3, 1) + ", " + rec.contains(3, 2) + ", " + rec.contains(3, 3));
```

Output:

- **true**, **true**, false
- **true**, **true**, false
- false, false, false

Then:

```
// I make sure again that the right-bottom point of my rectangle is (2,2)
// by checking the intersection result with another Rectangle
println("intersect (2,2): " + rec.intersects(new Rectangle(2, 2, 5, 5)));
println("intersect (3,3): " + rec.intersects(new Rectangle(3, 3, 5, 5)));
```

Output:

- intersect (2,2): true
- intersect (3,3): false

So from math point of view this is really rectangle 2 x 2 which has 4 integer points (that is 4 pixels): (1,1), (1,2), (2,1), (2,2). But what if we try to render it?

```
// Let's check what is get drawn
g.drawRect(1, 1, 2, 2); // displays 3 x 3 (as if width=3, height=3) !!
// Try it different way
((Graphics2D)g).draw(rec); // displays 3 x 3 again (as if width=3, height=3) !!
```

The yellow small rectangle is shown as 3 x 3:

[image: drawRect]

Conclusion: Rectangle() class constructor considers width/height as a real width/height of the shape in pixels, while drawing method drawRect() consider width/height as a shift relative to the left-top pixel.

So **java.awt represents the same rectangle as N x M for calculations, but as (N+1) x (M+1) when it is rendered with drawRect()**.

I find this totally wrong, because the default human logic is to suppose that we draw exactly what we have!

I wonder if someone else knows about this issue and can give some references to bug trackers or/and some logical explanations of such behavior. Just Google search gives me nothing about.

I wonder also how another programmers solve this problem. Use wrappers to drawRect pushing (x, y, width - 1, height -1)? I just can't believe that it is OK for everyone that it is working so weird like this.

UPDATE 1: Posting the "minimal" code snippet which reproduces the problem:

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        JFrame jFrame = new JFrame("Bug of drawRect() demo");
    JPanel jPanel = new JPanel() {
        @Override
        public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            g.drawRect(1,1,2,2);
        }
    };

    jFrame.add(jPanel);
    jFrame.setSize(400, 100);
    jFrame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    jFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    jFrame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

UPDATE 2: I am using OpenJDK 8 from https://github.com/ojdkbuild/ojdkbuild/releases. If I use "Go To -> Implementation(s)" in my IDE I see the drawRect() implementation here: C:\Program Files\ojdkbuild\java-1.8.0-openjdk-1.8.0.181-1\src.zip!\java\awt\Graphics.java.

```
public void drawRect(int x, int y, int width, int height) {
    if ((width < 0) || (height < 0)) {
        return;
    }

    if (height == 0 || width == 0) {
        drawLine(x, y, x + width, y + height);
    } else {
        drawLine(x, y, x + width - 1, y);
        drawLine(x + width, y, x + width, y + height - 1);
        drawLine(x + width, y + height, x + 1, y + height);
        drawLine(x, y + height, x, y + 1);
    }
}
```

In this implementation I see that it draws the second and the third line at "x + width" instead of "x + width - 1" which causes the bug.

Comment: `g.fillRect(1, 1, 2, 2);` - is only a 2x2 square for me. It appears to me like it paints as described in the API. I use JDK 8 on Windows 7. Post a proper [mcve] demonstrating the problem, not just a few lines of code.

Comment: Sorry, you are right about fillRect. But drawRect() still has an issue.
I have updated my question accordingly and put the reference to the JDK which I am using and the implementation of drawRect() from there which proves that it is wrong. Can you please confirm that you also have an issue with drawRect()?

Comment: `But drawRect() still has an issue.` - no it doesn't. It paints as described in the API. Read the API for the two methods and you will see the difference.

Comment: I read it at https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/Graphics.html#drawRect-int-int-int-int-. I see that the current behavior is expected from the sentence "The left and right edges of the rectangle are at x and x + width.".

However the parameter description "width - the width of the rectangle to be drawn" below is wrong on my opinion, because it is not actually a width.
The width is the number of pixels of the edge which is actually displayed, saying strictly. Are you agree?

Comment: I think people in general understand the term "width" to mean from a starting point you go to the right. What other term would you use if you don't think "width" is appropriate. The API then defines the behaviour in more detail to fully explain how the "width" parameter is used. It may not be perfect, but what I think is irrelevant since the behaviour is well documented.

Comment: >>>  What other term would you use if you don't think "width" is appropriate.
drawRect(int x, int y, int dx, int dy). "dx" and "dy" would mean "shift relative to ...". Nevermind... It is working so and it is documented so and I it obvious for me that nobody will change it.

However I don't understand what was the purpose of that +1 right and bottom. Why not making it with indeed "width" like fillRect from the beginning. Because it really confuses the programmers who expect/prefer verbatim meanings and strict formulations.

Answer (score 1):

As I ran into the same problem, with the code below (it is more complex than that), it took me some time to understand what I was doing *wrong* (I put emphasis here, like you, I think the API is wrong: you draw rectangle of 100x100, it should result in 100x100, not 101x101.):

```
    public class MyComponent extends JComponent {
      @Override
      public void paintComponent(final Graphics g) {
        g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        g.fillRect(0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight());
        g.setColor(Color.RED);
        g.fillRect(0, 0, 100, getHeight());
        g.setColor(Color.WHITE);
        g.drawRect(0, 0, 100, 100);
      }

      public static void main(final String[] args) {
        final JFrame frame = new JFrame("Test");
        frame.setSize(150, +156);
        frame.getContentPane().add(new MyComponent());
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setVisible(true);
      }
    }
```

This result in the sample window, where we can see the drawn rectangle having one additional pixels on width/height.

[image: Rectangle]

This is problematic in my case, because I am calling repaint with the region in which I'm drawing the rectangle. So:

- I am calling repaint(0, 0, 100, 100)
- Swing repaint the 100x100 square
- The white line is still there because it was not repaint.

The problem is that the `Graphic` class is not homogeneous in how it use the width and height, as one can see in the below Javadoc extract:

- From [drawRect](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/Graphics.html#drawRect-int-int-int-int-) javadoc:

  > Draws the outline of the specified rectangle. **The left and right edges
  >   of the rectangle are at x and x + width.** The top and bottom edges are
  >   at y and y + height. The rectangle is drawn using the graphics
  >   context's current color.
- From [fillRect](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/Graphics.html#fillRect-int-int-int-int-) javadoc:

  > Fills the specified rectangle. **The left and right edges of the
  >   rectangle are at x and x + width - 1**. The top and bottom edges are at
  >   y and y + height - 1. The resulting rectangle covers an area width
  >   pixels wide by height pixels tall. The rectangle is filled using the
  >   graphics context's current color.

**Fixing such an API is hard because code depending on it would fail** (because to fix the actual problem with code above, I would pass 99x99 to have 100x100 rectangle: fixing the API would result in a 99x99 rectangle).

You may expect this to never be fixed unless the class is retrofitted into a new package (probably merging `Graphics2D` along the way).

**TL;DR:** you should probably create a static method `drawRect` doing the same as `fillRect`, like below:

```
public static void drawRect(Graphics g, int x, int y, int w, int h) {
  g.drawRect(x, y, w - 1, h - 1);
}
```

Comment: I know the topic is old but I just fell into the trap, and I think programmers of Graphics2D also did. My issue was similar to this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21359095/only-1-corner-is-rounded-when-i-call-fillroundrect - You paint a 100x50 rectangle, it actually takes 101x51 but the Graphics2D still considers it's 100x50 and crops the extra pixel. Probably the "antialiasing trick" turns computations into float where such problems don't exist anymore.